# GeoPackage performance big dataset

Tags: qgis, geopackage

I am exporting a large dataset from PostGIS to GeoPackage and then trying to use it in QGIS and ArcMap. The GeoPackage size is 17Gb and contains around 6 different tables. The biggest table contains around 200million linestring features.

I have created the GeoPackage using ogr2ogr 2.1.3 which automatically adds a spatial index and am using QGIS 2.16.3 and ArcMap 10.4.

When I try and open the GeoPackage in QGIS it takes well over two hours before QGIS becomes responsive and starts to render the features at which point I can add a stylesheet or restrict the zoom ranges.

How can I use this GeoPackage more efficiently?

Do I need to VACUUM ANALYZE it like I would in PostGIS?

Or do I need to somehow add the stylesheet to the GeoPackage to restrict showing features at to high zoom levels.

Extra Details:
Windows Server 2012 64Bit 16Gb RAM

Comment: Turn off rendering until you've set the style

Comment: @iant I can't because QGIS becomes totally unresponsive while it seems to read the geopackage before even attempting to display the features

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a geopackage file using a command like the following:
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" destinationfilename.gpkg PG:"host=localhost user=myusername dbname=mydbname password=mypassword" "tablename"

If you are mainly looking for a way to visualize your data I suggest you rather install a [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) instance, map your data through it (preferably using PostGIS as your source) and connect to your data using WMS from the client software (QGIS or ArcMap). Use the [integrated geowebcache](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/) Geoserver. You can even manage geoserver from a [plugin in QGIS](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/qgis-geoserver-plugin/).

If you plan on doing spatial operations on the data set I suggest you keep your data in PostGIS and do the operations there. You could also use [FME from safe software](http://www.safe.com/) to do this as part of an export process.

Answer (score 0):

Before you open the GPKG, go into QGIS > Settings > Options and select the 'Rendering' tab. Untick the option 'By default new layers added to the map should be displayed'. That will stop newly loaded files from rendering until you tell them do, in the display panel.

There's also a setting for rendering with multiple cores that might help once you choose to display the data.

What I'm suggesting here is just a cosmetic fix. As ragnvald notes, the better option for data this large is probably to set up and work with a streaming connection. WFS will be be necessary if you're doing more than just looking at the data.